# Optimizing Forge Design Automation calls

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have Revit Add-in that I'm converting to Design Automation (DA) Add-in. Addin takes input as xml file and outputs rfa file. On Revit side code executes in about 0.5s, but when I upload it to DA it takes about 30s - 40s to execute. I'm trying to cut down on this time. So far I have tried Storing template file in AppBundle according to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle and moving my storage to EMEA region. This cuts down my time to about 20s - 30s. My goal is about 10s, what else could I try to further cut down execution time?

Comment: Check your report from work item and analyze what is the bottleneck. Use this report for logging what your addin does. I'm using log4net with trace appender and it works very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, caching your templates in the AppBundle is the recommended approach. Adam Nagy's [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle) is a good reference. As also suggested in comments looking up report.txt for bottlenecks is a good practice.

However, unfortunately there is a known overhead for running Design Automation in Revit. Starting up Revit and loading your addin in DA for Revit can take up to 20 secs (give or take). At this point we can't do better than that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you clarify if starting up Revit and loading addin is included in [pricing](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing) of DA?

Comment: We charge from the moment we start the download to the point we end upload. These times are indicated in your workitem status response as `timeDownloadStarted` and `timeUploadEnded`.

This includes the time needed to startup Revit and load your appbundle.